# Re-enable flychecksyntax checker after reported too many errors

Tags: flycheck

I recently ran into this error from flycheck:

```
Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker csharp-omnisharp-codecheck reported too many errors (482) and is disabled.
```

I saw this: [Warning (flycheck): Syntax checker javascript-eslint reported too many errors (494) and is disable](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14017/warning-flycheck-syntax-checker-javascript-eslint-reported-too-many-errors-4/14042) - which is great, but it doesn't answer the question "what do I do now?"

I got to this point by removing a closing brace, and of course everything broke. I replaced the brace, but now the syntax checker is disabled, and it doesn't show any errors.

So, how do I turn it back on?

Answer (score 1):

I think I stumbled on an answer:

When I selected the same checker, a buffer opened, and it said "Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers."

So:

```
 C-u C-c ! x
```

Then enter the name of the checker.

I hope someone has a simpler answer!